# Multiple background images not working

Tags: css, image, background

I'm trying to use two different background images assigned to the body tag. One in the top left, the other in the bottom right. I'm using the following code, but its only displaying the one or the other, not both. Please assist to point out what (if anything) I am doing wrong? I've tested in latest versions of FF and Chrome.

```
background-image: url(images/bg_top.png), url(images/bg_bottom.png) ; 
background-position: top left, bottom right; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-attachment: scroll; }`
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with your actual background images?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just changed order of the images and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try `fixed` the second image

```css
body{
    background-image: url(https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DJJX.png) ; 
    background-position: top left, bottom right; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat; 
    background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
    background-size: 150px,150px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but even making second image 'fixed' does not solve the problem. Still not showing second image.

Comment: try give them a size `background-size: 150px,150px;`

Comment: Have given them a size background - still not showing second image

Comment: check this path please `images/bg_bottom.png`

Comment: nothing wrong with the path. When I change the images around it displays the other one at the top. For some reason its not allowing both to be displayed at same time